# Rxjava split getting contacts

Tags: android, contacts, rx-java2

I need to split getting contacts from phone's contact list database. If user has a lot of contacts loading stucks for few seconds to load what is not very good. I want to divide it with Rx to load 20 contacts a time, but with loading all contacts on start, not with lazy loading. At this moment i tried it with pull of observables with concat, but it collects all the results and return after finishing all of them instead of returning every 20 contacts after getting them and just after returning continue with next pack of contacts. What is wrong with this implementation?

```
 @Override public Observable<List<Contact>> getPhoneContacts() {
    return Observable.fromCallable(this::getCursor)
        .concatMap(cursor -> {
          List<Observable<List<Contact>>> list = new ArrayList<>();
          int pagesCount = cursor.getCount()/20 + 1;
          for(int i = 0; i < pagesCount; i++){
            list.add(Observable.just(getContactList(cursor)));
          }
          return Observable.concat(list).compose(upstream -> {
            cursor.close();
            return upstream;
          });
        });
  }

  private List<Contact> getContactList(Cursor cursor) {
    List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed() && areContactsPresent(cursor)) {
      while (contacts.size() < 20){
        if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            Contact contact = getContact(cursor, id);
            if (contact != null) {
              contacts.add(contact);
            }

        }
        //else {
        //  cursor.close();
        //  break;
        //}
      }
    }
    return contacts;
  }

  private Cursor getCursor(){
    return contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
        null, ContactsContract.Data.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER+">0", null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
  }

  private Contact getContact(Cursor cursor, String id) {
    Contact contact = null;
    Cursor phonesCursor = contentResolver.query(
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
        null,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
        new String[]{id}, null);
    if (phonesCursor != null) {
      while (phonesCursor.moveToNext()) {
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String phoneNo = phonesCursor.getString(
            phonesCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        if (!phoneNo.isEmpty()) {
          contact = Contact.create(name, phoneNo);
        }
      }
      phonesCursor.close();
    }
    return contact;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You source observable needs to look something like that

```
Observable.create((ObservableOnSubscribe<List<Contact>>) emitter -> {
    int pagesCount = cursor.getCount()/20 + 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < pagesCount; i++){
        emitter.onNext(getContactList(cursor)); // Passes list with 20 items to onNext()
    }
    emitter.onComplete();
});
```

Your data source now returns `List<Contact>` instead of a single `Contact`, which means each emission will provide you with a list of contacts, each list has 20 items as per your implementation.

Then you can update UI with each emission, instead of waiting for all of the contacts to load.